# Automating scripts in q/kdb

Tags: automation, kdb

I have some codes in kdb+(which uses q) which generates data in tabular form. The problem is I need to run each line separately and export the data to excel. Is there any way to automate this such that all the excel files can ben generated in one go?
Thanks

Comment: Just save the data into csv or tsv text file, then open it with excel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whils't you can of course use csv as suggested above, .h.edsn is the function used for creating excel workbooks. It takes a dictionary of sheetNames->tables.

```
`:/var/tmp/excel.xls 0: .h.edsn `tab1`tab2!(([]10?10);([]20?20))
```

Then just open the xls file in excel.

Comment: I tried this line but I cannot seem to find the place where it is saving the excel file. Btw I am running my code and pulling data from an online server rather than a local host. Do you have any idea where it's saved?

Comment: @uchiha.itachi It should be saving the excel file to /var/tmp/excel.xls. See Save Text section on this page: http://code.kx.com/wiki/Reference/ZeroColon